# Новый фрагмент вместо TabLayout, ViewPager, ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Использую: `TabLayout`, `ViewPager` with `ViewPagerAdapter` чтобы показать 2 фрагмента. Когда пользователь нажимает на элемент в любом из этих фрагментов, то  нужно показать новый (третий) фрагмент. Как это лучше сделать?

`TabLayout` нужно убрать/сделать невидимым при показе нового фрагмента.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

mVPAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment1(), "F1");
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment2(), "F2");
viewPager.setAdapter(mVPAdapter);

tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Comment: Использую :  tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setVisibility(ViewPager.INVISIBLE); чтобы сделать невидимым tabLayout, но как дальше показывать 3й фрагмент - не понимаю.

Comment: Что должно произойти с теми двумя фрагментами в ViewPager'е? Должна остаться возможность переключаться между ними жестом? Если нет, то похоже, что лучше всего будет либо заменить весь фрагмент с TabLayout'ом и ViewPager'ом на третий фрагмент, либо даже проще — запустить новое Activity.

Comment: Нет, новое активити нельзя. А где почитать как заменить фрагмент с TabLayout'ом и ViewPager'ом на третий фрагмент?

Comment: Для начала, TabLayout и ViewPager должны быть в отдельном фрагменте. А чтобы заменить один фрагмент на другой, нужно использовать `FragmentTransaction.replace()`, как написано здесь во втором листинге: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions